# Discord.py find a member by name and move member to voice channel

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to create a command `!move username` which moves the specified user to a specific voice channel.

I can't get it to work and I'm not really sure why as I don't get any error messages.

Code:

```
@bot.command(name='move', pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def move(ctx, arg):
    channel = bot.get_channel(00000000000000000)
    member = Guild.get_member_named(arg)
    await member.move_to(channel)
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Can you add a print() for both arguments passed to the move function so I can see the output? What libraries are you using? This can be because the arg is a list or a dictionary and not a string.

Comment: The 5th line must be `member = ctx.guild.get_member_named(arg)`, then it should work.